# smesynccenter --hidden --syncall

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I installed `sme` storage to use onedrive.

Something did not work and `sme` was uninstalled but now I have this in System Register:

```
ct4er-linux CRON[4119]: (ct4er) CMD (DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY; LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8; export LANG; /usr/bin/smesynccenter --hidden --syncall
```

How to stop this?

Answer (score -1):

You should look for an entry with a similar command in the crontab. Delete the entry in the crontab.

For listing the crontab:

```
crontab -u [user] -l
```

Then remove the entry.